# How do I draw a single circle on a frame in OpenCV/Python while continuously updating the x-y position and redrawing?

Tags: python, macos, opencv, image-processing, drawing

I want a circle to be drawn on the first frame of a video based on a mouse click, and the circle refreshed if the user selects another position (i.e. only one circle should be drawn on the frame at a time).  To do this, I copy the original image after the initial frame capture, and revert back to this every time before a new circle is drawn.

In my real code the xpos and ypos are responsive to mouse clicks and radius to trackbar input, but below I have just incremented x and y systematically inside the while loop for simplicity (the code below still does not behave as I expected).

What I get from this code is a bunch of circles drawn on the first frame, not one at a time as I expected.

```
firstframe = 1 
cv2.namedWindow('test')    
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
if cap.isOpened():
    ret, originalframe = cap.read()  # read frame 1
frame = originalframe
cap.release()

xpos = 10
ypos = 10


while (firstframe == 1):
    frame = originalframe  #revert to the original frame
    cv2.circle(frame, (xpos, ypos), 100, (0, 255, 1), thickness=1, lineType=8, shift=0) #draw circle
    xpos = xpos +10        #move circle pos
    ypos = ypos + 10       #move circle pos
    cv2.imshow('test', frame)     #draw
    if cv2.waitKey(33) & 0xFF == ord(' '):       #hit space-bar when done...
        firstframe = 0
```

This is a cropped screenshot of the output -- too many circles:

[image: This is a cropped screenshot of the output -- too many circles]

I am running Mac OS X 10.9 w/ Python/OpenCV 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`frame = originalframe` will only point the `frame` to the data pointed by `originalframe`. Right now in your code the circle is drawn on the original data itself!

You will have to create a copy of data for the `frame`:

- CloneImage: clone an IplImage to another IplImage.
- CloneMat  : clones a Mat type to another Mat type.
- Copy      : copies the data, if the header is already defined.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally pasted my debug code there :0 fixed it.  I will try your suggestion when I get back to my computer - makes sense.

Comment: And the copyTo function as mentioned in Dima Maligin's code too could be used. But I do not know whether its equivalent is available in python.

Answer (score 1):

The following is in c++ but the opencv is pretty straightforward. the program does exactly what you need! you need to set a call back to update the mouse position. It is probably better to draw the circle elsewhere so you wont need to pass the frames to the callback but in a small program like that it dosent make much of a deference.

```
#include "opencv\cv.h"
#include "opencv\highgui.h"

void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* myData){
    cv::Mat frames[2];
    frames[0]=((cv::Mat*)(myData))[0];
    frames[1]=((cv::Mat*)(myData))[1];
    if(event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP){
        frames[1].copyTo(frames[0]);
        cv::circle(frames[0], cv::Point(x,y), 100, cv::Scalar(0,255,0));
    }
}

int main(){

    cv::VideoCapture vidBuffer("tmp.mp4");
    cv::Mat frames[2];
    if(vidBuffer.isOpened()){
        vidBuffer.read(frames[0]);
        frames[0].copyTo(frames[1]);
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
    frames[0].copyTo(frames[1]);
    cv::namedWindow("window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::setMouseCallback("window", onMouse, (void*)(&frames));
    char c=-1;
    while((c=cv::waitKey(40))!=' '){
        cv::imshow("window", frames[0]);
    }
    vidBuffer.release();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try.  Do you mean that I can draw the circle in another layer to save computation from redrawing the entire frame?  I didn't know opencv could do layers - that would be really useful.

Comment: @user391339 No what i ment is, if you noticed i am passing a referance to an array with 2 Mat objects. its not really a very good idea. insted its better if the onMouse function will only set the coordinates for the circle and the drawing of the circle will be done outside of the onMouse function.